# How can a user differentiate the salesforce contacts and outlook sync. contacts?

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

Actually my problem is that "Can we identify the contacts that are being imported from outlook into sales-force" is there any sign that helps the user to be clear that "Oh, this contact is from outlook.." and "Ah, This is a sales-force Contact.." kind of thing. Like a checked check-box for outlook contact and unchecked check-box for sales-force contact.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a custom Outlook field sync to a custom Salesforce field. See [Editing Your Salesforce for Outlook Field Mappings](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_personal_config_mapping.htm&language=en_US) for more information on mapping custom fields. It will still take some effort on part of the user to make sure that they're filling out the custom field/setting a known value to report on. I'm pretty sure you could write a macro to automatically populate the correct value. It will take some moderate effort to make this work, however.